# Directional derivative, gradient and a differential function

Tags: calculus

Let there be some function $f$, some point $(x_0,y_0)$ and some vector $u$.

Is $D_{u}f(x_0,y_0)=∇f(x_0,y_0)⋅u$ always correct? Even if the the function is not differentiable at the point? Or in more general, I didn't quite understand when that statement **is** true.

Thanks in advance for any explanation!

Comment: If the function isn't differentiable at that point, what would $\nabla f(x_0,\,y_0)$ be? Oh, wait, the vector of partial derivatives, probably. Then the answer is no. If the partial derivatives (directional derivatives parallel to the axes) exist, not all directional derivatives need to exist. And even if all directional derivatives exist, the equation need not hold.

Comment: @DanielFischer $\nabla f$ would be the 2-vector of partial derivatives.

Comment: So this applies always? Even if $f$ isn't diffrentiable? So, basically, if I'm asked to find the directional derivative for some vector I could just find the gradient and find the dot product of the vector with the gradient? And it'll always work out?

Comment: @ohad It'll work out if the function is differentiable at that point.

Comment: If the function is not differentiable at a point you **cannot** use the gradient/derivative in a formula! The formula is true **only** when the function is differentiable at that point.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!

Comment: @copper.hat: You're wrong about $|x|$ unless you have a non-standard definition of directional derivative. I usually see $\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\dfrac{f(a+tv)-f(a)}t$, not limit as $t\to 0^+$.

Comment: @TedShifrin: You are right, I have spent too much time in the convex/non-smooth domains. I usually think of the directional derivative as the one sided version (as in the generalized directional derivative of Clarke). I will remove my earlier comment. (However, I do think the one sided version is more natural, since otherwise one is ignoring the direction to some extent, just as north and south are different.)

Comment: @copper.hat: I agree on all counts. Of course, we can next debate whether $v$ and $-v$ are parallel! :)

Comment: @TedShifrin: You will win; classical geometry was never my strong point :-).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The directional derivative can be expressed as a dot product with the gradient if the function is differentiable. Otherwise the formula $D_u f=\nabla f \cdot u$ may fail: you can take 
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} \frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2} & (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\ 0 & (x,y)=(0,0) \end{cases}. $$
as a counterexample